# $x_t := a_t -b_t c_t $ , with $dx_t = \theta (\mu-x_t) dt+ \sigma dW_t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I would like to solve the following equation explicitly using Ito's lemma:
$$
x_t := a_t -b_t c_t  ,
$$
where $x_t$ is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process))
$$
dx_t = \theta (\mu-x_t) dt+ \sigma dW_t
$$

Can I simply use the solution provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process)? So:

$$ f(x_t, t) = x_t e^{\theta t}$$
and then:

\begin{align}
df(x_t,t) & =  \theta x_t e^{\theta t}\, dt + e^{\theta t}\, dx_t \\[6pt]
& = e^{\theta t}\theta \mu \, dt + \sigma e^{\theta t}\, dW_t.
\end{align}
$$
x_t  = x_0 e^{-\theta t} + \mu(1-e^{-\theta t}) + e^{-\theta t}\int_0^t \sigma e^{\theta s}\, dW_s.
$$

Comment: are you trying to relate $a_t,b_t$ and $c_t$ to something?

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes I would like to eventually have a separate equation for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly found $x_t$ as

$$x_t=x_0e^{-\theta t}+\mu (1-e^{-\theta t})+\sigma e^{-\theta t}\int_0^te^{\theta s}dW_s$$

We can rewrite this as

$$x_t=a_t-b_tc_t$$

where

$$\begin{align}
&a_t=x_0e^{-\theta t}+\mu (1-e^{-\theta t})\\\\
&b_t=-\sigma e^{-\theta t}\\\\
&c_t=\int_0^te^{\theta s}dW_s
\end{align}$$

---

Note,

$$dx_t=da_t-c_tdb_t-b_tdc_t$$

with

$$\begin{align}
&da_t=\theta(\mu- a_t)dt\\\\
&db_t=-\theta b_tdt\\\\
&dc_t=e^{\theta t}dW_t
\end{align}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
dx_t&=da_t-c_tdb_t-b_tdc_t\\\\
&=\theta(\mu-a_t+b_tc_t)dt-(-\sigma e^{-\theta t})(e^{\theta t}dW_t)\\\\
&=\theta(\mu-x_t)dt+\sigma dW_t
\end{align}$$

as expected!!

Comment: Why did the Wiener term disappear?

Comment: @student441 Good catch.  A typo that has been edited.

Comment: @student441 it shouldn't of disappeared. Because as it stands the function is purely deterministic .. Also $\theta$ is not a function of $t$ (or at least as stated in the problem) so $s$ should not be subscript. So OP don't follow this answer until he makes a few changes.

Comment: @Chinny84 The typo has been edited.

Comment: @Dr.MV What bothers me is that when $\sigma= 0 $, we get $b_t=0$ and $x_t = a_t$, while if we go back to $dx_t = \theta (\mu-x_t) dt+ \sigma dW_t$ for $\sigma=0$ we get: $d x_t= \theta (\mu-x_t) dt$ where $x_t=a_t+b_t$.. Can you explain?

Comment: @Dr.MV Furthermore, you define $a_t$, $b_t$, $c_t$ yourself, while they can be some given function already...(?)

Comment: @student441 If $\sigma =0$, then $b_t=0$.  So, you are correct that $x_t=a_t+b_t=a_t$ since we noted already that $b_t=0$.

Comment: @student441 If $x_t=a_t-b_tc_t$, and $dx_t$ is the OU process, then the terms $a_t$, $b_t$, and $c_t$ must be consistent so that $a_t-b_tc_t=x_t=x_0e^{-\theta t}+\mu(1-e^{-\theta t})+e^{-\theta t}\int_0^t e^{\theta s}dW_s$.